# the method hasNextline() does not work

Tags: java, netbeans

Why doesn't the method hasNextLine() work in Netbeans 8.1? When I press ctrl+z or ctrl+d nothing happens.Thanks

```
while (kb.hasNextLine()) {
        String str = kb.nextLine();//reads the transaction
        //isVallid checks if the transaction is valid 
        if (!isValid(str)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The transaction is not valid");
        }

        int x, y;//the valuse of x and y
        x = getX(str);//recognize and convert the valu of x to integer.
        y = getY(str);//recognize and convert the valu of y to integer.

        if (buyOrSell(str))//buyOrSell can recongnoize we buy or we sell.
        {
            justAddToQueueu(myQueue, x, y);// buy
        } else {
            capitalGain += removeAndCalculate(myQueue, x, y);// sell
        }
        System.out.println("Please enter the next valid transaction:"
                + "\nor press ctrl+D(ctrl+Z for mac) for exit.");
        //for exit you can press ctrl+D (or
```

Comment: I defined kb like this: Scanner kb=new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: before providing any input you are trying to check kb.hasNextLine() which is returning false

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "does not work"? Does the code compile? Does it run? Does it throw an exception? Where do you run it? How do you run it?

Comment: the code compiles and it runs. but when I press ctrl+D I do not get of the while loop!!!

Comment: The EoT(End-of-Transmission, `CTRL+D`) character does not clear all of the input from `System.in`, that assumption makes no sense.

Comment: Show the complete code. Are you silently discarding an exception?

Comment: so what do you recommend me to do?

Comment: What you're trying do is listen for keyboard events, which vanilla Java doesn't support. Java is meant to be portable, operating systems handle keyboard events differently, thus Java doesn't handle key events.

Comment: but the confusing point is: when I run this cod on bluej it works well, but not on netbeans

Answer (score 2):

Please note that due to the OP creating a moving target question, this answer is no longer applicable.

The reason is once you call the `hasNextLine`, it passes that and won't go back to it. So the `String str=kb.nextLine();` is now looking past that. Also, keep in mind the scope of a variable is inside the brackets it's declared in. So your 'str' isn't accessible in the rest of the program. What you'll have to do is something like this:

```
String check;
String str = "";
while(true){
    check = kb.nextLine();
    if (check.matches("^.+"))
        str += check;
    else
        break;
    }
```

Assuming, of course, that the purpose of your while loop was to accumulate all the user input into one String. If not, just remove the `+` from the `+=`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: OP wants to know why `CTRL+D` doesn't break out of the `while` loop.

Comment: Yes. This was posted before that was added by the OP. Originally, they asked why their while loop wouldn't work (Note the title) @JonnyHenly

Answer (score -1):

I think you cound be use `hasNext()` rather than `hasNextLine()`. this is the reason :

> You did not specify which version of hasNext() you meant, but basically, as long as there is another token in the data source that the scanner has encapsulated, hasNext() returns true.hasNextLine() on the other hand returns true if there is another line of input available, not just another token.